# JavaScript - Splitting string by multiple regex patterns returns undesired values

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

#### The Setup

I have a string, something like:

*`Sample Strings`*

```
val4[3].sub1[ 1 ][2].smth.esl

// or

val4.sub1

// or

val4.sub1[2].smth

// and so on...
```

The string will always abide by the following rules:

- The string always starts with characters belonging to `A-Za-z0-9_-`
- Every period must be followed by at least one of `A-Za-z0-9_-`
- Every opening bracket `[` has a matching closing bracket `]`

  - Every set of brackets contains an integer, with optional leading and trailing spaces

Think of the string in the same way you'd access items in an associative array. For example, the first string listed above might access an array like:

*`Sample Array Structure`*

```
val4 =  [
            0, 
            'some string', 
            2, 
            {
                sub1:   [
                            [1, 2, 3], 
                            [
                                'val',
                                1, 
                                {
                                    smth:   {
                                                esl: 'final value'
                                            }
                                }
                            ], 
                            [4, 5, 6]
                        ], 
                sub2: 'another str'
            }, 
            4
        ];
```

and the value at `val4[3].sub1[ 1 ][2].smth.esl` is `final value`.

Albeit the array is a nightmare, but just to help understand the acceptable patterns in the input strings.

#### Desired Behavior

What I am trying to do is split the string by the following:

- Periods and any following text belonging to `A-Za-z0-9_-`

  `/\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/g`
- Bracket pairs with integer contents and optional pre/aft spaces

  `/\[\s?[\d]+\s?\]/g`

So, using the first string as an example again:

```
val4[3].sub1[ 1 ][2].smth.esl
```

would split into

*`Desired Output`*

```
val4
[3]
.sub1
[ 1 ]
[2]
.smth
.esl
```

You can see [at this RegExr](http://regexr.com/3e48l) what the desired groupings should be.

#### The Trials

[JSFiddle of code](https://jsfiddle.net/um9wrah2/2/)

When I run the following:

*`Code Block #1`*

```
var str = 'val4[3].sub1[ 1 ][2].smth.esl';

var re = /(\[\s?[\d]+\s?\])|(?=\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+))/g;   

var splits = str.split(re);
```

*Note: In the regex expression, I've made the second pattern a positive lookahead (`?=`), so that the periods remain with the chars that follow*

I end up with the following:

*`Output #1`*

```
splits = [
            "val4",
            "[3]",
            null,
            ".sub1",
            "[ 1 ]",
            null,
            "",
            "[2]",
            null,
            ".smth",
            null,
            "esl",
            ".esl"
         ];
```

The result is pretty close, with a few notable exceptions:

- `splits[2]`, `splits[5]`, `splits[8]` and `splits[10]` are null
- `splits[6]` is an empty string
- `splits[11]` is missing the preceding period (and is really just an incorrect duplicate of `splits[12]`)

Running this with *only* the brackets part

*`Code Block #2`*

```
var re = /(\[\s?[\d]+\s?\])/g;
```

returns:

*`Output #2`*

```
splits = [
            "val4",
            "[3]",
            ".sub1",
            "[ 1 ]",
            "",
            "[2]",
            ".smth.esl"
         ];
```

Running this with *only* the period/chars part

*`Code Block #3`*

```
var re = /(?=\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+))/g;
```

returns:

*`Output #3`*

```
splits = [
            "val4[3]",
            ".sub1[ 1 ][2]",
            "smth",
            ".smth",
            "esl",
            ".esl"
         ];
```

But both of the preceding have their own flaws (empty values, strings without their accompanying periods).

I've said "I'm *so close*" with regex stuff before, and have been miles off. But, I feel like I'm right on the cusp.

***So, how can I mod the regex/split to accomplish what I'm after?***

Basically, no null or empty values returned, and only strings *with* their preceding periods.

Hopefully I've been clear, please let me know if any ambiguity.

#### Important!

For proposed solutions, it needs to be...

1. Browser-Independent

   This means likely nothing from ES6, since browser support for the new content is very inconsistent. People cannot be forced to adopt a browser just to run this.
2. Easily ported over to PHP (Preferred, but not absolutely critical)

   This has a sister script written for server-side operations. Keeping away from *JavaScript-Specific* technologies will help implement it in both languages.

#### Additional (Not Essential)

*(For those interested in the context and purpose)*

Spoiler alert! There really is an array. Not identical to `val4` defined above, but not dissimilar, and never the same twice.

```
val4 =  [... and so on...];
```

A string is provided (*must* be a string type)

```
str = 'val4[3].sub1[ 1 ][2].smth.esl';
```

And the return must be the value in `val4`, at the address in `str`.

```
var val4 =  [... and so on...];

var str = 'val4[3].sub1[ 1 ][2].smth.esl';

var result = getItem(val4, str);
```

Would literally return

```
return val4[3].sub1[1][2].smth.esl;
```

If you've got a bangin' way to do what I'm trying to achieve, without all the regex, I'm happy to hear it. But still interested in the primary issue laid-out in the question.

Comment: would you please start getting serious and actually read the answers/comments you receive. You are asking us for help.

Comment: @Thomas, I've got 8 windows open running all of the suggestions you've all given me, trying to figure out the direction to go in. I already have looked at your answer, that's where your +1 came from. But in interest of brevity, I was entertaining georg's solution for a bit to see how it might work out.

Comment: OK, but I didn't mean that my answer is the only right one. It feels like you are reading the comments only superficially, and that only half of it get's to you, and that is very frustrating and upsetting. I'd say you also hear that in the way Redu answered your comment.

Comment: And about the regex in georgs answer. I'm aware of the flaws it has *(although these are only flaws as long as you expect to get faulty inputs, wich should be avoided)*, that's the reason my regex is more specific about the pattern it allows, and still, without the second regex that validates the whole string, my regex would have similar problems to georgs. So take a look at this part of my code, try to understand how it works, and you might want to combine it with georgs or Radu's code/approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume in the end it's this you want to build.

I slightly extended the Regex to also parse things like `["lorem ipsum"]`

```js
 //parses the path into an Array of keys
 var parsePath = (function(){
  var fetchParts = /\[\s*(\d+|"(?:\\[\s\S]|[^\\"])+")\s*\]|(?:\.|^)([A-Za-z_$][A-Za-z_$0-9]*)/g;
  var isValid = new RegExp("^(?:" + fetchParts.source.replace(/\((?:\?\:)?/g, "(?:") + ")+$", "")
  
  return function(str){
   var s = str == null? "": String(str).trim();
   if(!isValid.test(s))
    throw new Error("invalid path: "+JSON.stringify(str));

   for(var m, keys = []; m = fetchParts.exec(s);)
    keys.push(m[1]? JSON.parse(m[1]): m[2]);
   return keys;
  }
 })();

 //takes a path or an Array of keys and returns a function that resolves the path from the passed object.
 //returns undefined if path can't be resolved;
 
 //v1
 var resolvePath = function(path){
  var keys = Array.isArray(path)? path: parsePath(path);
  return keys.reduceRight(
   (nextFn, key) => obj => obj != null && key in obj? nextFn(obj[key]): void 0,
   v => v
  );
 }

 //v2
 var resolvePath = function(path){
  var keys = Array.isArray(path)? path: parsePath(path);
  return function(obj){
   for(var i=0; i<keys.length; ++i){
    if(obj == null) return void 0;
    obj = obj[keys[i]]
   }
   return obj;
  }
 }


 //usage:
 var getSmthEsl = resolvePath('val4[3].sub1[ 1 ][2]["lorem\\nipsum"].smth.esl');

 console.log("a", getSmthEsl({
  val4: [
   null,    //0
   null,    //1
   null,    //2
   {            //3
    sub1: [
     null,    //0
     [            //1
      null,    //0
      null,    //1
      {            //2
       "lorem\nipsum": {
        smth: {
         esl: {
          sucess: true
         }
        }
       }
      }
     ]
    ]
   }
  ]
 }))
 
 console.log("b", getSmthEsl({ val4: [] }))
```

Comment: In the end, it's a combination of using the verification presented in this answer, and then combing through with the `find` function you wrote in georg's comments. With a slight modification to move away from `window.val4` that his answer requires.

Comment: [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dswub063/3/) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler than you think:

```js
window.val4 =  [
            0, 
            'some string', 
            2, 
            {
                sub1:   [
                            [1, 2, 3], 
                            [
                                'val',
                                1, 
                                {
                                    smth:   {
                                                esl: 'final value'
                                            }
                                }
                            ], 
                            [4, 5, 6]
                        ], 
                sub2: 'another str'
            }, 
            4
        ];


let ref = 'val4[3].sub1[ 1 ][2].smth.esl'


let result = window; // or 'global' in node

ref.replace(/(\w+)|\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]/g, (_, $1, $2) => result = result[$1 || $2]);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can this be ported to PHP as well, using the `preg_replace` method?

Comment: Arrow Functions have [poor browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility). As mentioned in another answer, I need something in pure vanilla JavaScript, that is browser independent.

Comment: @georg, may throw if some intermediate result is missing. how about this? `function find(str, ctx){
  var s = str == null? "": String(str), regex = /(\w+)|\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]/g, $;
  while($ = regex.exec(s)){
    if(ctx == null) return void 0;
    ctx = ctx[ $[1] || $[2] ];
  }
  return ctx;
}`

Comment: @Thomas I'm still playing around with your guys' solutions, but in the comment you just posted, you need to move `ctx = ctx[ $[1] || $[2] ];` outside of the `if == null` condition. Otherwise `ctx` is never set, and just returns the same object you pass in.

Comment: The problem I'm having with both of your solutions is that the regex `/(\w+)|\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]/g` allows for improperly-formatted inputs. Inputs like `val4[3!].sub1[1][2].smth.esl` *(has `"!"`)*, `val4[3]sub1[1][2].smth.esl` *(missing `"."`)* and `val4[3].sub1!??[1][2].smth.esl` *(has `"!??"`)* all return `final value`. I don't want it to be so loose - either the string entered is correctly formatted, or it's wrong.

Comment: @Birrel, it is not in the condition. The return statement is in the condition. And about the regex, this code was only meant to "fix" the problem with throwing errors, if the path can't be resolved on the passed object. For everything else you might want to take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39195767/6567275)

Comment: @Thomas I see, you're right. I think JSFiddle added extra brackets in when I copied and pasted it. With regards to the regex, any thoughts? Another issue I've found is that it just looks for the next match, with no regard for what's in between. This means that `val4[3].sub1[1!][2]` would produce the exact same answer as `val4[3].sub1[2]`, because it'll just skip over the `[1!]`. Same deal for `val4[3].sub1!??@#[1][2]`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

OK for this job you need to be able to set the object properties dynamically. Previously i had done a code for that purpose. `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()`.

**setNestedValue([prop1[, prop2[, prop3...]]],value)** works exactly like it's twin `getNestedValue()` but the last argument is the value to set. If the property does not exist it will create an object or array depenging on the type of the provided argument. Again, a string type argument will result an object while a number type argument will result an Array of that size.

Lets see the code.

```js
Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                       : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                         this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
               : this[a[0]] = a[1];
  return this;
};

var str = "val4[3].sub1[ 1 ][2].smth.esl",
    arr = str.split(/\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]|\./)
             .filter(prop => prop)
             .map(prop => Number.isNaN(+prop) ? prop : +prop)
             .concat("final value");
 result = {}.setNestedValue(...arr);
 console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,4));
```

I first show how the resulting arguments array to invoke `setNestedValue(...arr)` and then the resulting object.

Oh my bad...! I thought you wanted to construct the object dynamically however you like to get the nested value dynamically from an already constructed object.. `Object.prototype.getNestedValue()` is ideal for this job. We already have our object constructed anyways so lets use the above code again and get the nested value dynamically.

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};

Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                       : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                         this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
               : this[a[0]] = a[1];
  return this;
};

var str = "val4[3].sub1[ 1 ][2].smth.esl",
    arr = str.split(/\[\s*(\d+)\s*\]|\./)
             .filter(prop => prop)
             .map(prop => Number.isNaN(+prop) ? prop : +prop)
             .concat("final value"),
  myObj = {}.setNestedValue(...arr),
  value;

arr.pop(); // lets remove the "final value" since now we will get it.
value = myObj.getNestedValue(...arr);
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Just get compile errors. Plus Arrow Functions have [poor browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility). I am interested in vanilla, browser-independent JavaScript.

Comment: Firstly this is vanilla JS. I am giving you the regex and the algo to get the nested value dynamically. If i were you, i would first put Safari aside and test the code with Chrome or FF. Then i would study the code and make something out of it and convert it myself instead of waiting for silver spoon. If you could not convert `.filter(prop => prop)` into conventional function form i guess you have bigger problems than this question.

Comment: "Vanilla" was a poor choice. I meant more like "works in all major browsers". In regards to the "bigger problems", I don't make a habit of wasting my time using tech that requires people to change browsers (except IE), so until just today I had never used the notation before. Figured it out just fine shortly after my comment. That being said, I haven't looked at your code since, 'cause no one wants to decipher unreadable multi-level nested shorthand rats nests. I heard that you're allowed to use more than one line inside of functions. But maybe just a myth.